# Swagger Error Expected type string but found type integer

Tags: java, yaml, swagger

I started working recently on swagger to generate documentation for our RESTful apis. I use the yamlbeans-1.09.jar to convert my Java DTOs to a yaml file.
Everything works fine and the yaml is even validated properly on the http://www.yamllint.com/ but still while testing it with the Swagger interface, it gives an error ***"Expected type string but found type integer"***  and ***"No enum match for: 2"*** wherever I mention the swagger : 2.0 in the file.

My sample yml file is:

```
basePath: /employment
host: api.xxxx.com
schemes: 
    - https
swagger: 2.0
info: 
    title: API Doc
    description: Description for the info goes here
    version: 1.0.0
```

It always tends to give an error just a line number before the swagger version. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:** I have defined the swagger version as string in the java code and written as described below:

```
HashMap<String, Object> rootElementsForYml = new HashMap<String, Object>();
rootElementsForYml.put(SWAGGER, "2.0");
rootElementsForYml.put(HOST, "api.xxxx.com");
rootElementsForYml.put(BASEPATH, basePath);
rootElementsForYml.put(SCHEMES, new String[]{"https"});
```

But still it gives no result and the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the version value is a string and not a number. Just specifying `2.0` is interpreted as a number. Wrap it with quotes like `"2.0"` and it would work fine.

Comment: Well, this happens to be the final yaml where you can see that everything irrespective of it being a url or a number is written without quotes. While defining the data in Java code, I have kept the swagger version as a String which you can see in the **Edit** section of my original question. It picks the host, the basepath etc perfectly except the version.

Comment: That looks like a bug in yamlbeans as it doesn't respect the type being a String and does not serialize it properly. Most strings don't need to be wrapped by quotes, but if they represent other data types (numbers, boolean), they need to be wrapped.

Comment: Also, not really sure why you chose this path of manually creating your own yaml rather than use swagger-core.

Comment: If it was an issue with yamlbeans then at least the yaml-lint validations should have failed as well. As you can see I have specified the version as a String between quotes. But all the validations passed except for this version number thing.

And as far as using swagger-core is concerned, I was just experimenting with creating yml for the time being so went with yamlbeans. But as you said I will definitely give it a shot using swagger-core. Thanks!

Comment: yaml-lint would work fine because the YAML itself is valid. But a valid YAML doesn't make a valid definition. You can also write `hello: world` in the YAML and that would validate, but it is not valid as far as Swagger is concerned.